# Intellij Idea - how to obtain parallel scalatest execution INSIDE IDE

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

Using Sbt in order to run scalatest tests, 
you can put all test of a suite in parallel using the trait [ParallelTestExecution](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/ParallelTestExecution.html) and this works out of the box.

How to obtain the same result running scalatests tests inside Intellij Idea IDE? running test inside ide gives a better report and a colorful state of the results, better than sbt.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? 4.5 years later, I have the same issue (i..e. I want my tests to run faster in the IDE by using all me processor cores).

Comment: @mabead no, i moved to pytest.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `-P` command line parameter to the scalatest invocation in your IntelliJ "Run/Debug Configuration" should do the job.

References:

- [Executing Suites in parallel](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#executingSuitesInParallel)
- [Test Scala applications using Scala Test](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html#test_scalaTest)